# Is writing $ = jQuery a better idea in WP?

Tags: wordpress

I write multiple Jquery in WP, but they use the non-conflict version i.e. jQuery.
So is it a better idea that in top of my app, i write

```
var $ = jQuery;
```

Then use functions with $ symbol
It works fine for me, but isn't that bad?

Comment: If you wrap your code in `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
});` you should be ok, don't see why that would be bad. Also: [noConflict()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe.
Less is more.
all depending on the coding style.